# How many subsets $S \subseteq [10]$ are there such that $|S| = 5$ and $S$ contains either $1$ or $2$ or both?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not quite sure on what expression to use. So far, I have $\binom{8}{4} + \binom{8}{4} + \binom{8}{3}$. My thinking with the 8 choose 4 is to choose 4 other numbers from the set, with either the 1 or 2 already in it. Then, the 8 choose 3 is to choose three numbers in a set with both 1 and 2 already in it. Is this the right thinking or is there a better method?

Comment: Your ways works, Another way is to subtract the combos with neither 1 nor 2 from the total..
$$N = \binom {10}5 - \binom 85$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Another way to think about it, which is common whenever there is a requirement like "containing 1 or 2 or both" is to think about which subsets do *not* satisfy this and use the complement rule.

There are $\binom{10}{5}$ subsets in total, and if a subset does not satisfy "containing 1 or 2 or both", then that subset contains neither 1 nor 2. There are $\binom{8}{5}$ such subests.

Therefore, we get $\binom{10}{5}-\binom{8}{5}$. You'll see that this and your answer both equal 196.